# Heroku - import discord throwing NameError

Tags: heroku, discord.py, nameerror

Heroku logs:

```
import discord.abc
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/abc.py", line 101, in <module>
SnowflakeTime = Union[Snowflake, datetime]
NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined.
```

Requirements.txt:

```
git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py
dnspython==1.16.0
PyNaCl==1.3.0
async-timeout==3.0.1
pandas
numpy
requests
```

The build succeeded, the bot crashes on startup.  The bot imports discord and the logs show it's throwing the error above when it gets there.  It works completely fine on my local machine.  I've also tried using different versions of python in runtime.txt.  Please advise, thank you!

Comment: Guess it is because you are importing discord.abc? If this is what you wanted maybe try it with `from discord import abc`?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to install the `master` branch which is under development and raises errors.
To get the latest version of discord.py from the git repo, use

```py
 git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py.git@1.7.2
```

`@v1.7.2` refers to the version

Or `discord.py` is available on PyPi, so you can directly install from it.

```
pip install discord.py==1.7.2
```